# Meaning of "Inherently random"?

Tags: meaning

According to dictionary.com, "Inherent" means:

> existing in someone or something as a permanent and inseparable element, quality, or attribute

I understand the standalone definition of inherent but do not understand the definition of the phrase "inherently random" in this context:

> ***"He cannot predict inherently random attacks."***

What does *"inherently random"* refer to in this context?

Comment: It's saying that the attacks are permanently and characteristically random. It's just part of the attack itself. Like "That man is inherently violent" would mean that  violence is a permanent  characteristic of that man.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that the attacks are planned by rolling dice.  This would assure they are random in nature.  "Inherently random" simply means that some aspect of the nature of the attacks causes them to be random -- it's "in their nature" to be so.

(Of course, simply using the term does not make it the truth.  Whether the attacks can be predicted or not would need to be determined somehow, to make the statement true.)

Comment: February 6, 2016. +1

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is saying that the nature of the attacks being referred to is that they occur randomly. Thus, randomness is an inherent property of the attacks.